# How to display multiple barcode images using php html?

Tags: php, html, image, barcode

I want to display multiple barcode images when i insert the number in textbox. For example, if i write 12345, it will display first image. Then when i insert another number 456789, it will display the second image below the first image. But my problem is the second image is same with the first image. Can someone help me to check my code. My php file name is "code39.php".

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="code39.php">

    Code:<br><input type="text" name="code"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);    

    $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :'code' ;

    $barcode = draw($code);
    echo $barcode."<br>";
    echo $barcode."<br>";

?>
```

I give half of code. And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/zendframework/zend-barcode and https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-barcode/.

Comment: @localheinz. How to run that zendframework file?

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but from what I hear, https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-barcode/intro/ and https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md are probably good starting points.

Comment: I already succeed. Thank you @localheinz. May God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code can success.

```
 <?php
        $Code39 = array(
    '0'=>'111221211',
    '1'=>'211211112',
    '2'=>'112211112',
    '3'=>'212211111',
    '4'=>'111221112',
    '5'=>'211221111',
    '6'=>'112221111',
    '7'=>'111211212',
    '8'=>'211211211',
    '9'=>'112211211',
    'A'=>'211112112',
    'B'=>'112112112',
    'C'=>'212112111',
    'D'=>'111122112',
    'E'=>'211122111',
    'F'=>'112122111',
    'G'=>'111112212',
    'H'=>'211112211',
    'I'=>'112112211',
    'J'=>'111122211',
    'K'=>'211111122',
    'L'=>'112111122',
    'M'=>'212111121',
    'N'=>'111121122',
    'O'=>'211121121',
    'P'=>'112121121',
    'Q'=>'111111222',
    'R'=>'211111221',
    'S'=>'112111221',
    'T'=>'111121221',
    'U'=>'221111112',
    'V'=>'122111112',
    'W'=>'222111111',
    'X'=>'121121112',
    'Y'=>'221121111',
    'Z'=>'122121111',
    '-'=>'121111212',
    '.'=>'221111211',
    ' '=>'122111211',
    '$'=>'121212111',
    '/'=>'121211121',
    '+'=>'121112121',
    '%'=>'111212121',
    '*'=>'121121211');



        $unit='px';//Unit
        $bw=2;//bar width
        $height=50*$bw;// px
        $fs=8*$bw;//Font size
        $yt=45*$bw;
        $dx=3*$bw;
        $x=4*$bw;
        $y=2.5*$bw;
        $bl=35*$bw;


        $unit1='px';//Unit
        $bw1=2;//bar width
        $height1=50*$bw1;// px
        $fs1=8*$bw1;//Font size
        $yt1=45*$bw1;
        $dx1=3*$bw1;
        $x1=4*$bw1;
        $y1=2.5*$bw1;
        $bl1=35*$bw1;


        function checksum( $string )
        {
            $checksum = 0;
            $length   = strlen( $string );
            $charset  = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%';

            for( $i=0; $i < $length; ++$i )
            {
                $checksum += strpos( $charset, $string[$i] );
            }

            return substr( $charset, ($checksum % 43), 1 );
        }
        function draw($str,$checksum=false){
            global $unit,$x,$Code39,$height,$bw;
            $str=strtoupper($str);
            if ($checksum) {
                $str=$str.checksum($str);
            }
            $str='*'.$str.'*';
            $long=(strlen($str)+3)*12;
            $width=$bw*$long;
            $text=str_split($str);
            $img='';
            $img.= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n";
            $img.= "<svg width='$width$unit' height='$height$unit' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\n";

            foreach($text as $char){
                $img.=drawsymbol($char);
            }

            $img.='</svg>';

            return $img;
        }

        function drawsymbol($char){
            global $unit,$Code39,$x,$y,$dx,$bw,$fs,$dx,$yt,$bl;
            $x+=$bw;
            $img='';
            $img.= '<desc>'.htmlspecialchars($char)."</desc>\n";
            $xt=$x+$dx;
            $img.= "<text x='$xt$unit' y='$yt$unit' font-family='Arial' font-size='$fs'>$char</text>\n";
            $val =str_split($Code39[$char]);
            $len=9;
            for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
                $num=(int)$val[$i];
                $w=$bw*$num;
                if(!($i % 2)){
                    $img.= "<rect x='$x$unit' y='$y$unit' width='$w$unit' height='$bl$unit' fill='black' stroke-width='0' />\n";
                }
                $x += $w;
            }
            return $img;
        }






        function checksum1( $string1 )
        {
            $checksum1 = 0;
            $length1   = strlen( $string1 );
            $charset1  = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%';

            for( $i=0; $i < $length1; ++$i )
            {
                $checksum1 += strpos( $charset1, $string1[$i] );
            }

            return substr( $charset1, ($checksum1 % 43), 1 );
        }
        function draw1($str1,$checksum1=false){
            global $unit1,$x1,$Code39,$height1,$bw1;
            $str1=strtoupper($str1);
            if ($checksum1) {
                $str1=$str1.checksum1($str1);
            }
            $str1='*'.$str1.'*';
            $long1=(strlen($str1)+3)*12;
            $width1=$bw1*$long1;
            $text1=str_split($str1);
            $img1='';
            $img1.= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n";
            $img1.= "<svg width='$width1$unit1' height='$height1$unit1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>\n";

            foreach($text1 as $char1){
                $img1.=drawsymbol1($char1);
            }

            $img1.='</svg>';

            return $img1;
        }

        function drawsymbol1($char1){
            global $unit1,$Code39,$x1,$y1,$dx1,$bw1,$fs1,$dx1,$yt1,$bl1;
            $x1+=$bw1;
            $img1='';
            $img1.= '<desc>'.htmlspecialchars($char1)."</desc>\n";
            $xt1=$x1+$dx1;
            $img1.= "<text x='$xt1$unit1' y='$yt1$unit1' font-family='Arial' font-size='$fs1'>$char1</text>\n";
            $val1 =str_split($Code39[$char1]);
            $len1=9;
            for ($i=0; $i<$len1; $i++){
                $num1=(int)$val1[$i];
                $w1=$bw1*$num1;
                if(!($i % 2)){
                    $img1.= "<rect x='$x1$unit1' y='$y1$unit1' width='$w1$unit1' height='$bl1$unit1' fill='black' stroke-width='0' />\n";
                }
                $x1 += $w1;
            }
            return $img1;
        }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="GET" action="code39exam.php">

        Code 1:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="code"><br><br>


        Code 2:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="code1"><br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="submit"><br><br>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);    

        $code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] :'code' ;

        $barcode = draw($code);
        echo $barcode."<br>";


        $code1 = isset($_GET['code1']) ? $_GET['code1'] :'code' ;

        $barcode1 = draw1($code1);
        echo $barcode1."<br>";

    ?>
```

[image]